Express.js request path is changing during request
I have a express.js application written in TypeScript and am getting a weird issue I have never seen before, some detail:
Whilst the request is being processed by the route - /api/webhook/sellix/<shopName> - the request changes the path - it goes to /sellix/<shopName> - and calls the catch route I have added for invalid routes which is using app.use, then returns a 404 error, however the main route is still processing the request and finishes processing it even after the wrong response has been sent.
This is my route code:
app.post('/api/webhook/sellix/:shopName', async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.webhook_token) { // Check if the user is authenticated
        return res.api.error('You must be authenticated to use this API.', 401);
    }
    if (!req.webhook_token?.routes.includes('sellix')) { // Check if the authentication token has access to this route
        return res.api.error('You do not have permission to use this API.', 403)
    }
    if (!req.body || !req.body.data) {
        return res.api.error('Invalid request', 400);
    }
    const shopId = req.body.data.shop_id;
    const headerSig = req.headers['x-sellix-unescaped-signature'];
    const secretKey = getEnv(`SELLIX_SECRET_${shopId}`); // Get the secret key from the environment
    if (!secretKey.isset) {
        return res.api.error('Invalid shop ID', 400);
    }
    const hmac = createHmac('sha512', secretKey.string!);
    hmac.update(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    const sig = hmac.digest('hex');
    if (timingSafeEqual(Buffer.from(sig), Buffer.from(headerSig as string)) === false) {
        return res.api.error('Invalid signature', 401);
    }
    const event = req.body.event;
    const discordId = req.body.data.custom_fields.discord_id.toString();
    const discordUsername = req.body.data.custom_fields.discord_user.toString().replace('#0', '');
    const shopName = req.params.shopName;
    if (!event || !shopId || !discordId || !discordUsername) {
        return res.api.error('Invalid request', 400);
    }
    if (!validUserId(discordId) || !validUsername(discordUsername)) {
        return res.api.error('Invalid user data', 400);
    }
    let endTimestamp: number;
    if (event.startsWith('subscription')) {
        let endPeriod = req.body.data.current_period_end;
        if (!endPeriod || isNaN(endPeriod)) {
            return res.api.error('Invalid subscription period', 400);
        }
        endTimestamp = endPeriod;
    }
    if (shopId == 0 && shopName === '...') {
        try {
            res.debug(`Updating subscription expiry for ${discordUsername}, end period: ${endTimestamp!}`)(3); // Extended express debug function
            if (event == 'subscription:created') {
                sendNotification('high', 'sellix_events', `Subscription created for ${discordUsername}`, 'Sellix API Event', 'sunglasses').catch(() => { }); // Sends a notification using ntfy
            } else if (event == 'subscription:cancelled') {
                sendNotification('high', 'sellix_events', `Subscription cancelled for ${discordUsername}`, 'Sellix API Event', 'hankey').catch(() => { });
            }
            // req.path is still correct
            await setSubscriptionExpiry(discordId, endTimestamp!); // Update the subscription status in the database
            // req.path is wrong and another route has been called
            res.debug(`Updated subscription expiry for ${discordUsername}, end period: ${endTimestamp!}`)(3);
            return res.api.success({ message: 'Event processed' }); // This response doesn't get sent
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Failed to update subscription expiry for ${discordUsername}, end period: ${endTimestamp!}\n\nFailed with error: ${err}`);
            sendNotification('urgent', 'sellix_errors', `Failed to update subscription expiry for ${discordUsername}\n\nFailed with error: ${err}`, 'Sellix API Error', 'warning').catch(() => { });
            return res.api.error('Failed to update subscription expiry', 500);
        }
    }
    res.api.error('Not implemented', 400);
});

This is my database function for updating the expiry:
function setSubscriptionExpiry(discordId: string, expiry: number): Promise<null> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(
            'INSERT INTO `users` (`userid`, `subscription_expires`) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `subscription_expires` = ?',
            [discordId, expiry, expiry],
            (err) => {
                // I tested passing req to this function and logging it, right here is where path is changed, before the promise is made and before the pool.query it is still the correct path
                if (err) {
                    reject(`Failed to set subscription expiry: ${err}`);
                    return;
                }
                resolve(null);
            }
        );
    });
}

As you can see I have a few debug lines this is the output:
[1] [DEBUG-3] [127.0.0.1] [POST] /api/webhook/sellix/... Updating subscription expiry for ..., end period: 1716769402
[1] [DEBUG-2] [127.0.0.1] [POST] /sellix/... Not Found
[1] [DEBUG-3] [127.0.0.1] [POST] /sellix/... Updated subscription expiry for ..., end period: 1716769402

This is the route which is catching it and returning the 404:
app.use('/api/webhook', (req, res) => {
    if (app._router.stack.includes(req.path)) {
        res.api.error('Method Not Allowed', 405);
    } else {
        res.debug('Not Found')(2);
        res.api.error('Not Found', 404);
    }
});

Edit: The response sent to the request is as follows:
{"status":{"error":"Not Found","success":false},"data":{}}

When the path changes it fully does another request but in the same request, it is weird and the POST request finishes aswell it doesn't just stop but the response goes to that of the catch middleware.
Also for anyone wondering res.api is just a part of my extended types along with res.debug and others:
export interface Response {
    api: {
        success: (data: object, csrfOptions?: CSRFOptions) => void;
        error: (message: string, code: number, csrfOptions?: CSRFOptions) => void;
    };
    debug: (message: unknown, ...optionalParams: unknown[]) => (level?: number) => void;
    // rest goes here
}

Edit:
The routes are registered in the order showed above, app.post then app.use.
Edit:
Verbose output of cURL:
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:1337...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 1337
> POST /api/webhook/sellix/...?token=... HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:1337
> User-Agent: curl/8.6.0
> Accept: */*
> content-type: application/json
> x-sellix-unescaped-signature: ...
> Content-Length: 1636
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Accept: application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< ETag: W/"3a-dd81Vd9VmeuAAWodUEW8cNst4l8"
< Date: Tue, 28 May 2024 00:38:59 GMT
< Content-Length: 58
<
{"status":{"error":"Not Found","success":false},"data":{}}* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact

Edit: Implementations for Response.api:
res.api = {
    success: (data: object, csrfOptions?: CSRFOptions) => {
        if (csrfOptions) {
            // TODO: add CSRF handling
        }
        res.json({
            status: {
                error: null,
                success: true
            },
            data
        });
    },
    error: (message: string, code: number, csrfOptions?: CSRFOptions) => {
        if (csrfOptions) {
            // TODO: add CSRF handling
        }
        res.status(code).send({
            status: {
                error: message,
                success: false
            },
            data: {}
        });
    },
};

Edit: Response.debug implementation:
res.debug = (message: unknown, ...optionalParams: unknown[]) => {
    return (level?: number) => {
        // isProduction is a function which just checks an env var called PROD to see if its true and debug is at the top of my file and is also a env var called DEBUG
        if (isProduction() && !debug) {
            return;
        }
        if (level === null || level === undefined) {
            level = 0;
        }
        // logLevel is also a env var at the top of my file
        if (level && level > 0) {
            if (logLevel < level) {
                return;
            }
        }
        let ip = req.socket.remoteAddress || req.ip;
        // Cloudflare is not being used right now so this does not apply and is undefined
        if (req.headers['cf-connecting-ip'] !== undefined) {
            ip = req.headers['cf-connecting-ip']!.toString().split(',')[0];
        }
        console.debug(`[DEBUG-${level}]`, `[${ip || '127.0.0.1'}]`, `[${req.method}]`, req.path, message, ...optionalParams);
    }
};

Edit: I managed to find a workaround by changing my route to /webhook instead of /api/webhook and then putting the token in a param like /webhook/:token, I did this after removing ?token=... and changing the route to bypass authentication worked, apparently it was something to do with the way authentication was being handled that route didn't like.

res.api is part of my extended types its just what I use instead of having to type out the object response each time thats just for responses, also nope its not CORS this happens when im using cURL, and the request method is still POST so it cannot be pre-flight, this also would not explain why the path is changing mid request.

The logs are posted above in the question the method and path are in them, as you can see the path is changed mid-request and the method is always POST.

Yea trust me I thought it would be simple for the first 19 hours... then I came here.

The order is as showed in the question forgot to mention that will add that in now and nope no reverse proxy is involved as this is replicated on cURL directly to the express app.

Running with no -L option and will post the output of verbose in the question now.

Create a reproducible sample without your custom logic (database, notifications, etc) ans share us to help you. Sometimes doing this the developer find the error. When the express server starts, the request cannot be changed

res.api is not being called at all until after the path is changed, the path is changed as shown in the comment, when the pool.query finishes is the first time I see the path changed and the other request happen, but I will post them now.

Why is there an Accept header in the response?

Oh yeah that's just me being a little stupid that is added to all responses as I forgot to remove it, this project is not very well done but it works for the most part.

Ah, okay I will also add that.
